# Convert Decimal Time to human readable format using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime-conversion

I have a web service that returns the current time in Decimal format. How I can convert it to a human-readable format using JavaScript.

Here is what documentation says. The web service returns dates and times as floating-point values. The fraction represents the time (0.5 is noon).

e.g.

```
 0.5 is 12:00 

 0.681944 is 16:22
```

Comment: This is elementary school level math. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Convert the decimal representation to seconds in a day

```
const seconds = decimalData * 60 * 60 * 24
```

Take the reminder of `60` to the the seconds

```
const sec = decimalData % 60
```

Take the reminder of `3600` as the minutes divided by 60

```
const minutes = Math.floor((second % 3600) / 60)
```

Find the hour by div with 3600

```
const hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600)
```

Now you just have to convert it to a string.

```
const formatted = hours.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ":" + minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ":" + sec.toString().padStart(2, '0')
```

Comment: Thanks, @Radu Dita; can you please add the seconds part as well. How the seconds will be calculated in formated constant.

Comment: Dita maybe a bit off to the actual question. Is this possible to get the current system time in Decimal format? The same format in which I get the time from web service. I actually want to calculate the time difference in seconds between (current-system-time - web-service-time).

Comment: Yes, you can, but you should post another question regarding this.

Comment: Dita could you please answer here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61081381/how-to-get-current-time-in-seconds-decimal-using-javascript